# .htaceess redirect based on first parameter in url

Tags: .htaccess, server

I want to redirect `example.com/abc` to `example.com/myurl`
but url `example.com/abc/def` should not get redirected to `example.com/myurl`

I tried below code but it seems to both URLs below is my code

```
Redirect 301 /user https://example.com/myurl
```

Comment: Your question is not clear, to be more precise I couldn't understand what is aimed to deliver in the last sentence of yours. Please give example from your code and improve your explanation.

Comment: updated it please check

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod_rewrite on, use the below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule /[^/]*  https://example.com/myurl [R=301,L]
```

You could also use the  RedirectMatch directive if mod_alias enabled:

```
RedirectMatch 301 /[^/]* https://example.com/myurl
```

The above will match anything except slash in path

Comment: i want to redirect example.com/abc to example.com/def i can not see abc in above